# Polyhedra that cover the sphere more than once

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, spherical-geometry, tiling

[Spherical polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_polyhedron) can be thought of as tilings of the sphere. I am interested in the possibility of double covering or multiple covering tilings of the sphere, but I can't find much information about them and would like to know where I can learn more. (It might be that they are known by a different terminology.)

A "double covering tiling" would mean that as you add tiles to the sphere there will be a place where they don't line up, but if you keep adding tiles on top of the existing ones and keep going, they will line up once every part of the sphere is covered by exactly two tiles. This idea can be extended to triple cover tilings and so on, assuming those exist.

This idea has to be made precise in the right way - that's also part of the question. In the comments, Ivan Neretin gives an example that would make the question trivial, but it can be excluded by stipulating that the angles have to add up to $2\pi$ at each vertex, so let's add that as a requirement. (edit: or in fact let's not, since that would exclude multiple coverings entirely.)

It seems that double cover tilings exist and are known. Wikipedia's page on [uniform polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_polyhedron) says "There are some non-orientable polyhedra that have double covers satisfying the definition of a uniform polyhedron," but doesn't give further details except to say that they aren't usually counted as uniform polyhedra. A web page on [tiling the sphere with triangles](http://cs.stmarys.ca/%7Edawson/images4.html) states that the spherical triangle with angles 90$^\circ$, 75$^\circ$ and 45$^\circ$ will give a double covering of the sphere and that a 75$^\circ$-60$^\circ$-60$^\circ$ triangle gives a five-fold tiling.

In general I'm looking for more information about multiple covering sphere tilings, but here are my specific questions about them:

- Are there any/many other known examples of double coverings, aside from the 90$^\circ$-75$^\circ$-45$^\circ$ triangle?
- Are there any examples of double covering tilings that are made of regular polygons and are vertex transitive, as hinted at on the Wikipedia page? I would like to see a specific example.
- What about triple and higher order coverings - are there known examples beside the 75$^\circ$-60$^\circ$-60$^\circ$ triangle, and are there any composed of regular polygons? Do there exist $n$-fold coverings for every $n$?
- Are there "infinite covering tilings" in the sense that you can keep adding tiles in the same repeated pattern but the edges will never quite line up, so each part of the sphere will be covered by an infinite number of tiles? If so, are there such tilings where all the tiles are regular polygons?
- Is there a set of tiles such that you can always add more tiles, but *not* in a repeating pattern? This would be a spherical analog of aperiodic tilings of the plane, such as Penrose tiles.

Comment: Trivially, a spherical triangle with angles ${\pi\over2},{\pi\over2},{2\pi p\over q}$ would give you a $p$-cover.

Comment: @IvanNeretin thanks - I was worried about this kind of example. I think they can be excluded by stipulating that that each vertex the angles have to add up to $2\pi$. I'll edit something into the question along those lines.

Comment: From the same page as the double tiling (which, incidentally, has 45 as an angle, not 40): "*It can be proved that the 75°-60°-60° triangle cannot tile the sphere. However, it does permit a five-fold tiling of the sphere*".

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you, I hadn't spotted that - I've edited it into the question.

Comment: I feel this should be related to covering spaces. So if you have a $k$-fold cover of the some space than any tiling of the big space will give you a $k$-fold tiling of the small space. However the sphere is already its own universal covering space.

Answer (score 2):

What about projecting the great stellated dodecahedron = {5/2, 3}, the small stellated dodecahedron = {5/2, 5}, the great icosahedron = {3, 5/2}, or the great dodecahedron = {5, 5/2} onto the sphere? These 4 are the stary (non-convex) $regular$ polyhedra. - The set of the $uniform$ polyhedra contains even more stary figures. Many of them are orientable, so that those too can be projected onto the sphere to provide spherical tilings, which casually provide multicovors.

--- rk

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but it seems to me that the angles at each vertex would sum to $4\pi$ rather than $2\pi$ for these polyhedra - is that correct? (Thank you though, it's actually kind of an interesting possibility.)

Comment: {5/2, 3} and {5/2, 5} would provide, when projected back onto the sphere, a tiling each with $2\pi$ per vertex, while {3, 5/2} and {5, 5/2} would ask for $4\pi$ per vertex. In fact {p, q} refers to a tiling of p-gons, q around each vertex. And both p and q could be rational here. Then refering to p-grams for faces, or to q-grams for vertex figure, i.e. (for q=n/d) having n faces at a vertex, circling d times around.

Answer (score 1):

You even could consider {5/2, 4}. Again 4 is integral and the vertex configuration of 4 regular planar pentagrams is still less than the full circuit, so has an angular deficit, i.e. provides a spherical arrangement which furthermore has a local spherical vertex angle of $2\pi$ too. - On the other hand the numerators (4 and 5) are incommensurate (being ruled out as $finite$ Coxeter group, so the produced tiling does never end, i.e. it covers the sphere infinitely often.

--- rk

Comment: The elemental 36 - 60 - 90 dgr. triangle of [3, 5] is e.g. shown here: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3e/Sphere_symmetry_group_ih.png. The larger 36 - 72 - 90 dgr. triangle is seen there too if adding to the yellow part the 3 further elemental triangles at the left (up to the next blue 5-fold spot). This larger triangle tiles the sphere also, producing the same subdivision. As it has a 4 times larger domain it leads to a 4-fold cover. Similarily when the 3 triangles above (up to the pink rhomb) are added too: resulting in a 7-fold cover with a 60 - 72 - 90 dgr. triangle.